# How to get al repository users and their permissions using Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket-api

Im trying to retrieve all repository users and their permissions with Bitbucket API.
I found that it possible to find project users but not repository.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question?  I also am looking for a way to get all users listed in a bitbucket repo using the API